# One chapter without numeration

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters

How can I make one chapter (Introduction) without number?

I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}

\chapter{Introduction}  
\chapter{Chapter 1}  
\chapter{Chapter 2}
```

In ToC I have:

1. Introduction ..............1
2. Chapter 1 .................2
3. Chapter 2 .................3

I want to have:

Introduction .................1
1. Chapter 1 .................2
2. Chapter 2 .................3

I want introduction to behave just like the bibliography which is at the same level in ToC as chapters but without number.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

For the standard classes (`article`, `report`, `book`) you can use the starred version of `\chapter` which suppresses the number but also the TOC entry, so you hav to add it manually with `\addcontentsline`

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}  
\chapter{Chapter 1}  
\chapter{Chapter 2} 
\end{document}
```

or with KOMA-Script (`scrartcl`,`scrreprt`,`scrbook`) which provides `\addchap`  for this case (and `\addsec` of sections):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addchap{Introduction}
\chapter{Chapter 1}  
\chapter{Chapter 2} 
\end{document}
```

I don’t know about `memoire`’s behavior when using `\chapter`

Comment: Why `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}`? In my document, it works without this line.

Comment: @Ichibann: In this case you’re not using a standard class (article, report, book) in which the starred version suppresses the number but also the TOC entry. The `\addcontentsline{toc}{<level>}{<text>}` command writes the TOC entry. (See my edited post for KOMA-Script, which behaves in the same way for starred sectioning commands but provides the `\addchap` [and `\addpart`/`\addsec`] command[s]). See my edits …

Answer (score 4):

MWCLS supports `\chapter*` and you don't have to do anything more, it will end in TOC, because Polish rules require it.

Comment: What are Polish rules, prosze?