# Content - items disappeared

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I have problem with content. Yesterday was everything ok, but today List of figures and List of tables disappeared. I didn't do any changes with them. Moreover, I do not want to introductory chapter has a number, so I used \chapter*{introductory chapter}. This item disappeared from content too. Do anyone know what can I do about this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, we know what you can do: please compose a [`minimal working example`](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem with the lists, and add it to your question. For the introductory chapter, use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introductory Chapter}`.

Comment: The usual remedy for me for such cases is to first try re-running latex again. The TOC is generated based on the temporary files created by the first run. A subsequent run produces the TOC.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. I have tried re-running latex several times, but there is no improvement. However \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introductory Chapter} doesn't work the way I want. There is now line for Introductory Chapter in content, but references don't work and moreover it changed my numbering of items in other chapters.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}  \usepackage{amssymb,multicol,graphicx, fancybox,fancyvrb,natbib,bbding,booktabs,dcolumn,amsthm,amsmath,longtable,multirow,array,ltcaption}
\begin{document} 
\include{Bc_titulni} in this chapter there is a command \tableofcontents

\include{Bc_kap01} this is my introductury chapter
\include{Bc_kap02}
\include{Bc_kap03}

\include{Bc_konec}

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\end{document} I am sorry, but I haven't found how to write it synoptical :(

Comment: Hi everybody, I have found a solution, it's package \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}. So list of figures and list of tables are in content now. But there is still problem with the Introductery Chapter.

Comment: I have found solution here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22905/one-chapter-without-numeration. Anyway thank you for answers