# How can I skip sections in the numbering?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, structure

I have the following latex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{First}
% Content for the first section

\section{Second}
% Content for the second section

\section{Third}
% Content for the third section, which will be numbered as 1 in the PDF

\section{Fourth}
% Content for the fourth section, which will be numbered as 2 in the PDF

\end{document}
```

By default, I get the following output:

1. First
2. Second
3. Third

But what I want is:

- First
- Second
- 1. Third

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22905 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136527 […](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sectioning%2bnumbering).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.